# How do you change the time of the Linux hardware (hwclock) clock to 24-hour format?

Tags: linux, command-line, time, date-time, date

Currently, my hardware clock returns the date/time (hwclock --show) like this:

`Sat 28 Jul 2018 08:47:47 PM BST  .659124 seconds`

And date returns:

`Sat Jul 28 21:23:13 BST 2018`

**I'd like to change the time of the hardware clock to 24-hour format and the format of date to match the hardware clock's date/time format.**

I have searched high and low but haven't found thorough documentation on managing date and time on Linux systems (i.e., short, medium and long date, regional formats such as DD-MM-YYYY or DD/MM/YY), especially in a command line environment.

I have man'ed hwclock and date. They don't help. I also know that there are a set of similar questions that have been asked before. I have looked at them and they don't help either.

Can someone help with regards to my specific question noted above or point me to some thorough documentation with a discussion on how to deal with multiple date/time scenarios for different regions in a command line environment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Linux (distro) and version are you using?

Comment: Do you really want to reset bit 2 of Status Register B, or do you just want to *display* the time in 24h format?

Comment: Also, cannot duplicate. I get ISO 8601 format just like the man page says.

Comment: what locale and timezone are you using?

Comment: what does this get you? `LC_TIME=C hwclock --show`

Answer (score 2):

You can make `date` do the work for you: the `-d` option allows you to specify the date in a "mostly free format human readable date string" (from `man date`).

Unfortunately, the format isn't quite free enough to accept the `hwclock` output, but it works fine if you remove the final field specifying fractions of a second:

```
date -d "$(hwclock|sed 's/  \..*$//g')"
```

I have tested, but not managed to hit upon the format when there are zero fractions of a second, so I don't know if it would show the same format, eg `Sat 28 Jul 2018 08:47:47 PM BST  .000000 seconds`. If there is no decimal point, another `sed` replacement will be needed.

Provided that there is still a double space after the time zone, the following will work:

```
date -d "$(hwclock|sed 's/  .*$//g')"
```

You can make this a shell script or a function defined in `~/.bashrc` called something like `hwclockdf` (ie in `date` format).